# After update linux to version 4.2, Java write "Failed to write core dump"?

Tags: java, linux

I work on one programm, that need to java 7. But when I update archlinux to 4.2 (from 4.1) ,when I start the programm, java write me:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fdf76d41be0, pid=3512, tid=140597796308736
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007fdf76d41be0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/nozdrin/workspace/rvec/server/bin/hs_err_pid3512.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Java not update!! What happend with java and what do I need?

`EDIT:`

I found, when start the programm, he added keys `-J-XX:PermSize=200m \
-J-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`. When I delete this keys, java return another error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f164f6b0be0, pid=5145, tid=139733914535680
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007f164f6b0be0
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/nozdrin/workspace/rvec/server/bin/core or core.5145
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/nozdrin/workspace/rvec/server/bin/hs_err_pid5145.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

This errors appeared when I update linux. I tried return old linux 4.1, but error still.

File [hs_err_pid5145.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxaeNy8l4k8Sb295c2pMeXZ6ZEU/view?usp=sharing) - is link on Google Drive.

Comment: Have you tried to actually read the message? Because it tells you what you need to do.

Comment: Yes, and I do. But nothing change!

Comment: Did you try "ulimit -c unlimited"?

Comment: Could you post a log file from the report? /home/nozdrin/workspace/rvec/server/bin/hs_err_pid5145.log for example

Comment: @RomanPustylnikov, I want, but this file too big : `Body is limited to 30000 characters;`

Comment: Well, you can find some clues there, let us know if you see something suspicious.

Comment: @RomanPustylnikov I added link with the file!

Comment: Sorry, nothing interesting there. All I could think about is that this update brought some new libraries java was using (or even updated java itself) and now you have a mixed java installation. Try to reinstall java / make sure that the paths point to the right java.

Comment: @RomanPustylnikov, thank you for try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when I update to 4.4 kernel!
Thank all!